# Маршрутизация на Ubuntu

Tags: маршрутизация, ubuntu

Есть две сетевухи, два модема. Необходимо настроить маршрутизацию на компе таким образом чтоб она сетевая карта смотрела только на интернет, а вторая сетевая карта только на определенные IP. + Как настроить VoIP на Убунту (ExpresTalk) и еще пара виндовых программ которые работают опять же удаленно. Есть советы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Есть две сетевухи, два модема.

Это 4-е сетевых интерфейса?

> Необходимо настроить маршрутизацию на компе таким образом чтоб она сетевая карта смотрела только на интернет, а вторая сетевая карта только на определенные IP.

- route add default gw dev eth0
- route add -net xxx.yyy.aaa.bbb/сс gw dev eth1
- и т.д

А набор утилит iproute2 вообще творит чудеса.